# Get the instance on which another instance was created

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have three classes: `A`, `B` and `C`.

I create an instance of `C` on an instance of `A` and an instance of `B`:

```
class A; end
class B; end
class C; end

a = A.new
b = B.new

a.c = C.new
b.c = C.new
```

Can I get to the parent somehow? Like so:

```
a.c.parent #=> instance of A ( a == a.c.parent )
b.c.parent #=> instance of B ( b == b.c.parent )
```

Does something like this exists?

Comment: what is `a.c` and `b.c` ? I am trying to guess,but can't.. please you have to tell.

Comment: Looks like you're missing getter/setter methods :(

Comment: There is no real relationships between your classes. C is not a sub-class of A and B here. Do you simply want to simulate this behavior ? or you want to C to be a real sub-class ?

Comment: I know, but it's more an example of what I want.. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since in your example, `A.c=` is not yet defined anyway, you can define it like:

```
class A
  attr_reader :c

  def c=(x)
    @c = x
    x.parent = self
  end
end
```

and define `attr_accessor :parent` in class `C`.

There is no "ownership" relation in Ruby, so you have to model it yourself.

Comment: You'll want it to be `x.parent = self`

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! Too bad it doesn't exist, but it's pretty simple to set up anyway.. :)